# Bokeh can't set axis ticks font

Tags: python, bokeh

```
axis().major_tick_label_font    ="times"
axis()[0].major_tick_label_font ="times"
axis().major_tick_font          ="times"
xaxis().major_tick_font         ="times"
```

Nothing worked. How to set the font of the ticks? Not the axis label, but the ticks label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names of some of the properties are unfortunately a little overly verbose. Text properties all have basic names like `text_font_size` and then that may also have a prefix like `major_label`. (In this case, `major_label` is the "label for a major tick") So all together the proper attribute name is `major_label_text_font`.

You can see an example that sets similar properties here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes

And there is information in the docs about general properties here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html

Comment: Thank you, yes I already know the general properties guide, that's where I got the ideas from. Unfortunately the solution for my purpose wasn't clear to me after reading...

Comment: Yes after re-reading the User Guide I realized it could use some new attention, I made a ticket to do a refresh and update.Thanks for the questions!